# What are the ways to import a module/function?

Tags: python, function, program-entry-point, python-module

It is a very basic question, but I have not seen any explanation covering all possible cases so far.

Suppose `m1, m2, m3` are module hierarchies, and `fun()` is a function inside the hierarchy.

I have seen commands like

> ## Version 1
>
> ```
> from m1.m2.m3 import fun
> fun() #To access the function
> ```
>
> ## Version 2
>
> ```
> import m1
> m1.m2.m3.fun()
> ```

Are they exactly equivalent to

> ## Version 3
>
> ```
> import m1.m2
> m1.m2.m3.fun()
> ```

or

> ## Version 4
>
> ```
> from m1.m2 import m3
> m3.fun()
> ```

Or any other combinations in-between? Is there any relative advantage or disadvantage? Clearly, I would rather like to write `fun()` while calling the function each time rather than writing `m1.m2.m3.fun()` but what is the trade off?
From my understanding, version 2 will execute the whole script of m1. But are the others more selective in their execution (and hence possibly get to the `__main__` quicker?)

Comment: Have a look at [PEP 8 recommendations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).

Comment: Depends a lot on if you're going to be using other parts of the package. For example, if you only want to use `fun()`, then you should probably just import that, rather than importing the entire `m1`.

Comment: Another option would be to add `from .m2.m3 import fun` to `__init__` file of `m1`, and import `fun` as `from m1 import fun`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ## Version 1
>
> ```
> from m1.m2.m3 import fun
> fun() #To access the function
> ```

Version 1 is the one to go with **if** `fun` is the only function you want from the `m1` tree **and** you can guarantee that no other function inside your script will ever be called `fun`. If any of the above are not satisfied **do not do it**, but if the are, **do it.**

---

> ## Version 2
>
> ```
> import m1
> m1.m2.m3.fun()
> ```

Version 2 is the one to go with **if** you want to be able to access **everything** inside `m1`. It does lead to more verbose code because you have to carry the `m1` with you all the time but it is safer and far less obscure that the equivalent (which should be discouraged) `from m1 import *`. Note that `m1` code will be executed.

---

> ## Version 3
>
> ```
> import m1.m2
> m1.m2.m3.fun()
> ```

Version 3 is the one to go with **if** you want to be able to access **everything** inside `m2` but not higher (cannot do `m1.more_fun()`). Note that `m2` code will be executed.

---

> ## Version 4
>
> ```
> from m1.m2 import m3
> m3.fun()
> ```

Version 4 is the one to go with **if** you want to be able to access **everything** inside `m3` but not higher (cannot do `m1.m2.more_fun()`). Note that `m3` code will be executed.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any difference in terms of selective execution or do all of them execute the whole m1 before proceeding to execute '__main__'?

Comment: @Della There is. When you do `import m1.m2`, `m1` code is not executed; `m2` is. The same holds for `from m1 import m2`. I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 2):

one other way of importing is

```
import m1.m2.m3 as m
```

and hence u can call the function using

```
m.fun()
```

the most import thing to be careful about is not to override something that already exists ( polluting the namespace )